# How to set fixed ratio for image view without using support library?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I want my `ImageView` to have 16:9 ratio and `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

I cannot find out how to set it in `XML` file. I know there is a `PercentRelativeLayout` that can help. But it supports API 23 and I don't want to use it.

I know I can set the ratio programmatically. But it's not good. Because when the screen is rotated I have to set the size of `ImageView` again.

Is there any way to do it with `XML` file?

Answer (score 2):

To Create Percentage Ratio ImageView needs to Override the onMeasure method in ImageView.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    public class PercentageImageView extends ImageView {
        public PercentageImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public PercentageImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public PercentageImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        public PercentageImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PercentageImageView, 0, 0);
        try {
            heightRatio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.PercentageImageView_imageHeightRatio, 0f);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
        }


        @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightMode != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            if (heightRatio != 0) {
                height = (int) (heightRatio * width);
            }
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
    }
```

Inside values/attrs.xml

```
    <resources>

      <declare-styleable name="PercentageImageView">
          <attr name="imageHeightRatio" format="float" />
      </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
```

Send ratio from the XML like below

```
<PercentageImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:imageHeightRatio="0.569" />// This is for 16:9 ratio.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with Constraint layout and 0dp (match constraint) instead of match_parent, any idea what to do in the constraint layout?